Validating POST parameters with serializers in Django
I'm trying to implement a simple validator for my POST parameters
My input looks like this:
{
  "gage_id": "01010000",
  "forcing_source":"my_source",
  "forcing_path":"my_path"
}

I have the following Serializer:
class SaveTab1Serializer(Serializer):
    gage_id = CharField(min_length=1, required=True),
    forcing_source = CharField(min_length=1, required=True),
    forcing_path = CharField(min_length=1, required=True),

And I use it like this:
@api_view(['POST'])
def save_tab1(request):
    body = json.loads(request.body)
    ser = SaveTab1Serializer(data=body)
    print('serializer', ser.is_valid())
    print('errors', ser.errors)

But no matter what I do with the data, it only shows as valid with no errors.  Is there more code that I need to add to the serializer to do the validation?

This question is similar to: How to validate Post arguments in Django. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

That was my question.  I got an initial answer, but I'm still having a problem with the call to is_valid()

You have an almost unnoticeable syntax error in your serializer. Serializer fields should be added "stand-alone", you don't need (and shouldn't use) trailing commas. For reasons I don't know, that messes with the serializer's ability to process the fields properly.
Here's a standalone proof of concept:
# test.py
import json
from rest_framework             import serializers
from rest_framework.decorators  import api_view, permission_classes
from rest_framework.permissions import AllowAny
from rest_framework.response    import Response


class SaveTab1Serializer(serializers.Serializer):
    gage_id = serializers.CharField(min_length=2, required=True)
    forcing_source = serializers.CharField(min_length=2, required=True)
    forcing_path = serializers.CharField(min_length=2, required=True)


@api_view(['POST'])
@permission_classes([AllowAny])
def save_tab1(request):
    body = json.loads(request.body)
    ser = SaveTab1Serializer(data=body)
    print('serializer', ser.is_valid())
    print('errors', ser.errors)
    return Response({ "data": body, "data_is_valid": ser.is_valid(), "data_errors": ser.errors })

# urls.py
path('test/', save_tab1, name='test'),



By comparison, here's the same execution but with trailing commas:


Well, something is messed up because I get the same results with your test.  Copied exactly what you have into a separate file and added the Path to my urls.py.  Still always returns true, with no errors.  I don't think the trailing commas had anything to do with it.  All the imports are correct.  Can't imagine what it can be

I've added to the answer what I get if I use trailing commas in the serializer definition, so that's definitely one of the things that were amiss. But how & why the problem persists with the modified code is a little beyond me at the moment - I can't think of any obvious reason that'd be the case.

Oh, missed your last test where you show the trailing commas broke it.  That's weird, but I definitely don't have them in there anymore

I assume that there's nothing special I needed in setting.py or anything like that right? Just trying to figure out what could be different with my environment

No necessary settings.py as far as I know - mine don't have anything special for DRF anyway. I'm assuming you're looking at the print output in your console, right, and not the output from some other client? Because if it's an external client, there might be caching involved & the "incorrect" response could be the cached one.

Yup, looking at the console as well as in Postman. I thought of some caching issue as well. Even ended Pycharm and restarted
